# Responsive navigation bar using JavaScript is not resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, nav

I'm trying to create a responsive nav bar using jQuery and whatever I try just doesn't fix it.

**jQuery**

```javascript
$(function() {
    var pull = $('#pull');
    menu = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
};
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper clearfix">
    <header class="english">
        <div id="top-header">
            <a href="../index.html"><h1></h1></a>
            <h2></h2>
            <h2></h2>
        </div>

        <nav class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li class="menu-active"><a href="english.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="story.html">Our Story</a></li>
                <li><a href="ceremony-reception.html">Ceremony & Reception</a></li>
                <li><a href="accommodation.html">Accommodation</a></li>
                <li><a href="album.html">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="registry.html">Registry</a></li>
                <li><a href="guest-book.html">Guest Book</a></li>
                <li><a class="bsb" href="information.html">Information for Americans</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
nav {height: 40px; width: 100%; background: #B9DACC; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: relative;}
nav ul {padding: 0; margin: 0 auto; width: 960px; background: #B9DACC;}
nav li {display: inline; float: left;}
nav a {font-family: "coolvetica_rgregular",Arial,sans-serif; color: #fff; display: inline-block; padding: 0 12px; text-align: center;text-decoration: none; line-height: 40px;font-size: 16px;}
nav li:last-child a {border: none;}
nav a:hover, nav a:active {background-color: #F4C3AB;}
nav a#pull {display: none;}
```

I've been trying to add the most important for the WRD, the style with the `@media queries`, but it's not letting me because of indentation. Is there a way that I could send it?

Comment: What part isn't working?

Comment: Can you drop on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/). please?

Comment: @YeshanSachithaKPerera - please don't suggest people add links to external sites. They should be posting all the code needed to reproduce the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than performing resize operation in Jquery try to re size using CSS, with the help of media queries. Below is the sample of it. Give it a try.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
aside{
display:none;
}

#wrapper{
width:100%;
}

// Specify here the operation to perform when condition in met.
}
```